# Parsing and replacing special characters from file

Tags: c#, .net, special-characters, streamreader

I have the following text in a file...

`blah blah ñ blah`

Notice the **ñ**  symbol.

I'm reading this with `StreamReader.ReadLine` and then trying a `string.Replace` to replace the special character.

For some reason this isn't working, and it seems to be something to do with the `StreamReader`. When I inspect the string in the debugger after reading the line, I get that box shape that text editors display when they can't render a character.

Trying similar directly in code works fine...

`int test = "helloñworld".IndexOf('ñ');`

so I figure it must be the StreamReader.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using any encoding? See, this link may help you as it deals with some similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640242/file-encoding-when-reading-a-file-with-streamreader

Comment: I meant, is he specifically giving any particular encoding? Not the implicit one but explicitly specifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the StreamReader with the correct encoding of your text file using either the [StreamReader(Stream, Encoding)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456.aspx) constructor or [StreamReader(String, Encoding)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8xxf0x5.aspx). Common encodings nowadays are Latin 1 or UTF-8.

Comment: How do I know what encoding my text file is in?

Comment: @fear: You saved it, I presume. Depending on your editor that could be anything from the OEM charset (CP850 or 437), Latin 1 to Unicode (UTF-8 or UTF-16). I would guess CP1252 to be the most likely option, though.

Comment: No I didn't save it, it's an export from a 20 year old database. Anyway, with trial and error it seems UTF7 works.

Answer (score 0):

Set the correct encoding in overloaded Streamreader constructor.

Hope this helps,
 Ilya